# Find dataframe rows with all of list of strings in any of list of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of three terms that might appear in any of three columns. I'd like to find all the rows that have all three terms somewhere in the three columns.

### Starting with . . .

I've got a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
In [1]: data = [
    ['Missouri','Kansas City','Jackson County'],
    ['Boston','Massachusetts','Suffolk County'],
    ['Los Angeles','Los Angeles County','California'],
    ['Massachusetts','Suffolk County','Boston'],
    ['Philadelphia','Pennsylvania','Philadelphia County'],
    ['Kansas City','Missouri','Jackson County'],
    ['Kansas City','Missouri','Platte County']
]

In [2]: columns=['location0','location1','location2']

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)

In [4]: df

Out[4]: 
    location0       location1           location2
0   Missouri        Kansas City         Jackson County
1   Boston          Massachusetts       Suffolk County
2   Los Angeles     Los Angeles County  California
3   Massachusetts   Suffolk County      Boston
4   Philadelphia    Pennsylvania        Philadelphia County
5   Kansas City     Missouri            Jackson County
6   Kansas City     Missouri            Platte County
```

I want to get all of the rows of the dataframe that describe Kansas City, Jackson County, Missouri.

In other words, I want all rows where all of these three terms: ['Kansas City','Jackson County','Missori'] are in any of these three columns: ['location0','location1','location2']:

### Goal

The result would look like this:

```
    location0       location1       location2
0   Missouri        Kansas City     Jackson County
1   Kansas City     Missouri        Jackson County
```

### Tried unsuccessfully . . .

```
In [1]: look_for = ['Kansas City','Jackson County','Missouri']

In [2]: look_in = ['location0','location1','location2']

In [3]: result = df[col for col in look_in if df[col].isin(look_for)]

In [4]: result

Out [4]:   
File "<ipython-input-408-c42b1236af99>", line 3
result = df[col for col in look_in if df[col].isin(look_for)]
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Edited**: For typo in `look_for`

Comment: okay @reliz you can do `df[np.column_stack([df[col].str.contains('|'.join(look_for)) for col in df]).any(1)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) in filtered columns by filtered values and for test all `True` per rows add [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
result = df[df[look_in].isin(look_for).all(axis=1)]
print (result)

     location0    location1       location2
0     Missouri  Kansas City  Jackson County
5  Kansas City     Missouri  Jackson County
```

Answer (score 1):

```
look_for = ['Kansas City','Jackson County','Missori']
df[df.sum(axis=1).str.contains('|'.join(look_for))]
```

**Output**

```
     location0      location1       location2
0   Missouri        Kansas City     Jackson County
5   Kansas City     Missouri        Jackson County
6   Kansas City     Missouri        Platte County
```